# R: Extract substring and paste the same substring at the end of a string

Tags: r, string

I have some strings with the following pattern of: letters and numbers

```
A11B3XyC4 
A1B14C23XyC16 
B14C23XyC16D3
```

I want to extract the part "Xy" (always the same letters) and paste it at the end of the remaining string. The result schould look like this:

```
A11B3C4. Xy
A1B14C23C16. Xy
B14C23C16D3. Xy
```

Could you point me to a function capable of this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please Specify your language that you are using

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` and build groups in the `pattern` argument by wrapping them in `()`. We can access these groups in the `replacement` argument with `\\` followed by the group number.

```r
strs <- c("A11B3XyC4", 
  "A1B14C23XyC16",
  "B14C23XyC16D3")

sub("(.*)(Xy)(.*)", "\\1\\3\\. \\2", strs)
#> [1] "A11B3C4. Xy"     "A1B14C23C16. Xy" "B14C23C16D3. Xy"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Just `sub()` since you're looking for a single match. Maybe also anchor with `^...$`?

Comment: Thanks, as a habit I always use `gsub`, but your comment is totally correct, I updated my answer.